# Validate percentage value

Tags: javascript

I am validating percentage value:

```
validateFloatValue: function(value) {
    var number = parseFloat(value);
    if (isNaN(number)) {
        console.log("Invalid value");
    } 
}
```

Basically, value is passed as string. It passes for "33.45" which is fine. But, I do not want to allow user to enter "33.45%". But, in this case, there is no error for "33.45%" since parseFloat is converting "33.45%" to 33.45 `parseFloat("33.45")`. How can I throw error, if value is "33.45%"?

Comment: No need for using `parseFloat`. You can just simply check it with `isNaN`.

Comment: @Yogesh: You could use a `+` cast instead: `var number = +value`.

Comment: simple check if string contains "%" with indexOf .

Answer (score 2):

You can eventually exclude all things that does not match a regex... like if `value` not match `\d[.,]+\d` You should write a regex that match your needs ;)

```js
(function validateFloatValue(value) {
    var number = parseFloat(value);
    if (! /^\d+[., ]+\d+$/.test(value) || isNaN(number)) {
      document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = "Invalid value";
    }
})("12.34%");
```

```html
<div id=res></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Number.isFinite` validates input slightly more strictly:

```
validateFloatValue: function(value) {
    if (!Number.isFinite(number)) {
        console.log("Invalid value");
    } 
}
```

You can also use `isNaN` directly - it would be more portable:

```
validateFloatValue: function(value) {
    if (isNaN(number)) {
        console.log("Invalid value");
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only what  to check if the string contains %, you can use indexOf like this.

```
if (value.indexOf('%') === -1) {

} else {
  console.log("Invalid value");
}
```

If you want to check if the string is a number, you can try to convert the string to number using the Number function.

If the value cannot be converted to a legal number, NaN (Not a Number) is returned.

So you just have to verify if the result is NaN using the isNaN function like this :

var valueNumber = Number(value);

```
if (!isNaN(valueNumber)) {

} else {
  console.log("Invalid value");
}
```

Comment: It doesn't handle properly input like this: `12.3 spam`, which is still invalid.